# simple-php-captcha Error: Font file not found

Tags: php, captcha

I am trying to install this CAPTCHA script on my server:

http://www.abeautifulsite.net/blog/2011/01/a-simple-php-captcha-script/

I have uplaoded the files and tried to run the demo. However the CAPTCHA image does not display as it should.

When I try and open the CAPTCHA image directly, I get this error

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Font file
>   not found: ' in
>   /home/website/public_html/simple-php-captcha/simple-php-captcha.php:125
>   Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in
>   /home/website/public_html/simple-php-captcha/simple-php-captcha.php on
>   line 125

Code below:

```
Line 125: if( !file_exists($font) ) throw new Exception('Font file not found: ' . $font);
```

The font file path is set earlier in the code:

```
$captcha_config = array(
    'code' => '',
    'min_length' => 5,
    'max_length' => 5,
    'png_backgrounds' => array(dirname(__FILE__) . '/default.png'),
    'fonts' => array(dirname(__FILE__) . '/times_new_yorker.ttf'),
    'characters' => 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789',
    'min_font_size' => 24,
    'max_font_size' => 30,
    'color' => '#000',
    'angle_min' => 0,
    'angle_max' => 15,
    'shadow' => true,
    'shadow_color' => '#CCC',
    'shadow_offset_x' => -2,
    'shadow_offset_y' => 2
);

$font = $captcha_config['fonts'][rand(0, count($captcha_config['fonts']) - 1)];
```

I have checked and all the required files are in the folder.

Does anyone know how to fix this error?

Comment: Do a `echo($font);` before line 125

Comment: Thanks for the welcome. I tried an echo on $font and it appears to be empty! Do you know why this could be? I haven't modified the script at all. I played around a bit and `dirname(__FILE__) . '/times_new_yorker.ttf'` seems to empty the string. I'm not familiar with PHP. What does `dirname(__FILE__)` do?

Comment: Medical add `echo($font); exit();`, instead. If nothing appear, activate error reporting: `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` from script who calls the CAPTCHA library (like `index,php`)

Comment: I put the following before line 125: `$font = '/home/website/public_html/simple-php-captcha/times_new_yorker.ttf';` . That seems to have fixed it. Do you know why `dirname(__FILE__) . '/times_new_yorker.ttf'` doesn't seem to work?

Comment: Which file have `dirname(__FILE__)` defined?

Comment: `dirname(__FILE__)` is not for anyone to define as far I know, it simply returns the parent directory of the current PHP file, @GabrielSantos :)

Answer (score 0):

I've just found out that simple php captcha does no work with page caching and the exception "font file not found" is thrown some what falsely. I made sure that the page that has CAPTCHA image on it is not cached and problem is solved.

In my particular case, I have a page `/register/` which has a CAPTCHA image. I'm using W3 Total Cache to do page-caching for my WordPress website.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If Font is not showing in captcha, go to wamp server wampthemes then look for the font folder then search for the font you want. Right click on font properties, copy the path at $font['C://wamp/....../fonts/xyz.tff'] in your democatcha.php file, then it will work.